# Update hidden input with values typeahead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead as an autosuggest for a very simple web app. I am very new to javascript and jQuery. The web app is one input that will search the iTunes store and suggest results as the user is typing.

I have one version working, which will retrieve song names based on what the user is typing. What I'd like to be able to do, however, is update some hidden fields with other values (e.g. artist name, track id, preview url, etc.). I am trying to use the `filter` option to accomplish this, but am only getting back `undefined` in my search now.

Also, general tips re: javascript and jQuery would be appreciated. It's the next skill I want to work on.

For the relevant code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <title>HOLLAND</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js"></script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #111;
        }
        .content {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
            border: none;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
            height: 47px;
            width: 60px;
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }

        .tt-hint,
        .song {
            border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 45px;
            line-height: 30px;
            outline: medium none;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            width: 400px;
        }

        .tt-dropdown-menu {
            width: 400px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #111;
            background-color: #F1F1F1;
        }

    </style>
    <script>

    var resultList, d;

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input.song').typeahead({
                name: 'song',
                remote: {
                    url: '/Playlist/search.php?query=%QUERY',
                    filter: function(data) { <-- THIS IS WHERE I NEED ASSISTANCE

                                retval = [];
                                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                    retval.push({
                                        value: data[i].trackId,
                                        artistName: data[i].artistName,
                                    });
                                }

                                return retval;
                            }
                        }

            }).on('song:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
                $('#songID').val(d[resultList.indexOf(suggestion)].trackId);
            });

        });

        function printArray(arr){
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                if(arr[i] instanceof Array){
                    printArray(arr[i]);
                }else{
                    console.log(arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Playlist</h2>
        <form>
            <h1>Search Apple Music</h1>
            <input type="text" name="song" size="30" class="song" placeholder="Please enter song name">
            <input type="hidden" name ="songID">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php
    $key = $_GET['query'];

    $searchString = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" . urlencode($key) . "&limit=10&entity=song";
    $array = array();

    //  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    //No header return
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    //Use proxy
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "naproxy.gm.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "80");
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $searchString);
    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    // Will dump a beauty json :3
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo curl_error($ch);
    }
    else{
        $obj = json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);

    /*
    foreach($obj['results'] as $row => $value) {
        $array[] = $value['trackName'] . " by " . $value['artistName'];
    }
    */

    foreach($obj['results'] as $row => $value) {
        $array[$row] = array
            (
                'trackId', $value['trackId'],
                'trackName', $value['trackName'],
                'artistName',$value['artistName'],
                'previewURL', $value ['artworkUrl30']
            );
    }

    echo $array;

?>
```

response from iTunes

```
{
  "resultCount": 10,
  "results": [
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902180909,
      "trackId": 902180917,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackName": "Born This Way",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackCensoredName": "Born This Way",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way\/id902180909?i=902180917&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way\/id902180909?i=902180917&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a463.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music1\/v4\/d5\/3c\/07\/d53c0773-ff35-1fe5-9be2-815038285c08\/mzaf_4465142801402798156.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 10.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2013-01-01T08:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 22,
      "trackNumber": 2,
      "trackTimeMillis": 260258,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902096524,
      "trackId": 902096558,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way",
      "trackName": "Born This Way",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way",
      "trackCensoredName": "Born This Way",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way\/id902096524?i=902096558&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way\/id902096524?i=902096558&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a459.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music1\/v4\/c7\/2a\/83\/c72a8341-88b7-c65d-09dc-c333de92bb0c\/mzaf_4381737056492150878.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is1.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music3\/v4\/b9\/d2\/e8\/b9d2e809-eb0b-d2df-193b-5bc99b5e5ecf\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is1.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music3\/v4\/b9\/d2\/e8\/b9d2e809-eb0b-d2df-193b-5bc99b5e5ecf\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is1.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music3\/v4\/b9\/d2\/e8\/b9d2e809-eb0b-d2df-193b-5bc99b5e5ecf\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 7.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2011-02-11T08:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 14,
      "trackNumber": 2,
      "trackTimeMillis": 260258,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902180909,
      "trackId": 902180935,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackName": "The Edge of Glory",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackCensoredName": "The Edge of Glory",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/the-edge-of-glory\/id902180909?i=902180935&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/the-edge-of-glory\/id902180909?i=902180935&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a642.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music4\/v4\/bb\/93\/f6\/bb93f6dd-b09f-6378-9097-e41fab0a50e7\/mzaf_2685820553066586847.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 10.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2013-01-01T08:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 22,
      "trackNumber": 17,
      "trackTimeMillis": 321545,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902180909,
      "trackId": 902180934,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackName": "Yo\u00fc and I",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackCensoredName": "Yo\u00fc and I",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/yo%C3%BC-and-i\/id902180909?i=902180934&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/yo%C3%BC-and-i\/id902180909?i=902180934&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a37.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music1\/v4\/b3\/d0\/51\/b3d05174-db69-be68-272b-1b1dd35360d9\/mzaf_7395703188902498297.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 10.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2011-05-23T07:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 22,
      "trackNumber": 16,
      "trackTimeMillis": 307364,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 716415763,
      "trackId": 716415953,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "NOW That's What I Call a Workout",
      "trackName": "Born This Way (Bimbo Jones Club Remix)",
      "collectionCensoredName": "NOW That's What I Call a Workout",
      "trackCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bimbo Jones Club Remix)",
      "collectionArtistId": 4035426,
      "collectionArtistName": "Various Artists",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way-bimbo-jones-club-remix\/id716415763?i=716415953&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way-bimbo-jones-club-remix\/id716415763?i=716415953&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a294.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music3\/v4\/25\/47\/e8\/2547e80d-c74c-7cf4-7905-041c7f7ec259\/mzaf_1883593890824568199.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is5.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/a5\/ed\/99\/a5ed99e5-ca11-2a34-a72d-e86b2e11a1ba\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is5.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/a5\/ed\/99\/a5ed99e5-ca11-2a34-a72d-e86b2e11a1ba\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is5.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/a5\/ed\/99\/a5ed99e5-ca11-2a34-a72d-e86b2e11a1ba\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 11.99,
      "trackPrice": -1,
      "releaseDate": "2012-12-18T08:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 18,
      "trackNumber": 1,
      "trackTimeMillis": 284453,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Fitness & Workout",
      "isStreamable": false
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902180909,
      "trackId": 902180936,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackName": "Born This Way",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackCensoredName": "Born This Way (The Country Road Version)",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way-the-country-road-version\/id902180909?i=902180936&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/born-this-way-the-country-road-version\/id902180909?i=902180936&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a470.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music4\/v4\/76\/79\/3d\/76793d4c-0683-3793-0b02-7e8ced3ec1e1\/mzaf_5908951428023709023.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 10.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2011-05-23T07:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 22,
      "trackNumber": 18,
      "trackTimeMillis": 261276,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902180909,
      "trackId": 902180916,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackName": "Marry the Night",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackCensoredName": "Marry the Night",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/marry-the-night\/id902180909?i=902180916&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/marry-the-night\/id902180909?i=902180916&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a211.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music4\/v4\/74\/30\/24\/743024be-2c46-b876-5c39-ba6bdf94ec72\/mzaf_1169912516356657975.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 10.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2013-01-01T08:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 22,
      "trackNumber": 1,
      "trackTimeMillis": 264523,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902180909,
      "trackId": 902180938,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackName": "Judas",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackCensoredName": "Judas (DJ White Shadow Remix)",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/judas-dj-white-shadow-remix\/id902180909?i=902180938&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/judas-dj-white-shadow-remix\/id902180909?i=902180938&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a1915.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music4\/v4\/20\/95\/05\/2095055f-c724-b689-72bc-d0d747d5379d\/mzaf_3035200198497304749.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 10.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2011-05-23T07:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 22,
      "trackNumber": 19,
      "trackTimeMillis": 247483,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 277293880,
      "collectionId": 902180909,
      "trackId": 902180920,
      "artistName": "Lady Gaga",
      "collectionName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackName": "Judas",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Born This Way (Bonus Track Version)",
      "trackCensoredName": "Judas",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/lady-gaga\/id277293880?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/judas\/id902180909?i=902180920&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/judas\/id902180909?i=902180920&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a53.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music4\/v4\/bc\/9b\/d5\/bc9bd511-00b9-ebad-73df-62cdf01a26b4\/mzaf_8671438699719321037.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is3.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music1\/v4\/94\/8f\/b9\/948fb9ce-de93-fe33-e7b5-a8bdf5580178\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 10.99,
      "trackPrice": 1.29,
      "releaseDate": "2011-04-15T07:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 22,
      "trackNumber": 4,
      "trackTimeMillis": 249071,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Pop",
      "isStreamable": true
    },
    {
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 412537193,
      "collectionId": 446108937,
      "trackId": 446108958,
      "artistName": "Born This Way",
      "collectionName": "Poker Face - Single",
      "trackName": "Poker Face",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Poker Face - Single",
      "trackCensoredName": "Poker Face",
      "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/artist\/born-this-way\/id412537193?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/poker-face\/id446108937?i=446108958&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/poker-face\/id446108937?i=446108958&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "http:\/\/a578.phobos.apple.com\/us\/r30\/Music\/1b\/4b\/13\/mzm.uzkuoblk.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl30": "http:\/\/is4.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/95\/b5\/95\/95b59505-1d03-6a6d-4e36-e3b7219f7605\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http:\/\/is4.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/95\/b5\/95\/95b59505-1d03-6a6d-4e36-e3b7219f7605\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http:\/\/is4.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/95\/b5\/95\/95b59505-1d03-6a6d-4e36-e3b7219f7605\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 1.98,
      "trackPrice": 0.99,
      "releaseDate": "2011-06-17T07:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 2,
      "trackNumber": 1,
      "trackTimeMillis": 238653,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD",
      "primaryGenreName": "Dance",
      "isStreamable": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I suspect the issue is with how I am returning/parsing the array. When I look in the console, resultList gets set but it looks like the keys I intend (e.g. trackId, trackName, artistName, etc.) are actually stored as values in the array.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated. I am trying to update the hidden input songID with the value of the trackID returned in the array (I will also add a few others as I mentioned such as artist and preview URL).

Thank you!

Comment: Add ID="songID" to your input. `#` in jQuery refers to the element's ID, just like `.` refers the class.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that definitely is part of it. I think I am having trouble with the json that's returned though. I have updated my answer with what my response data looks like.

Comment: add `eval(data);` inside `filter: function(data)` and check if json was returned. If this is Ok, the next step is to do the json treatment to retrieve the relevant information.

Comment: An object is being returned. `Object {resultCount: 10, results: Array(10)}
resultCount: 10`

Comment: Partially figured out my problem. I was attempting to iterate over the JSON object and not the results array within the object. I corrected that. Next issue I am facing is with the `select` custom event for typeahead.

Comment: Nice! JSON is correct. Now try to loop the result using key/value like  `$.each(results, function() { eval(this.artistName); });`

Comment: It loops, but I'm just getting undefined `$.each(resultList, function() {
         console.log(this.artistName);
        });`

Comment: use `data.results` instead `resultList` on each

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149262/discussion-between-soulfire-and-pilha).

Answer (score 0):

change your code little like this:

```
filter: function(data) { <-- THIS IS WHERE I NEED ASSISTANCE
    $('name["songID"]').val(data[i].trackId);
retval = [];
..............
.........
...
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. I suspect I need to use the `select` custom event. How would it know which trackId to put in the hidden field? (I am returning a result list up to 10 items).